# Python - Chaining methods: returning `self` vs returning a new cloned object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Due to some restrictions in a project I'm working on, I had to replace Django's QuerySet class with a custom one.
QuerySet objects can have their methods chained (eg `QuerySet().filter(...).exclude(...)` and so on), so in my implementation, every method simply returns `self`. So my class looks like this:

```
class MyQuerySet:
    ...
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do some stuff and then:
        return self
```

This way I imitated Django's QuerySet behaviour.

*However*, looking at the Django code, I noticed that instead of returning `self`, QuerySet's methods return a cloned object every time they are called. It looks like this (removed unnecessary stuff):

```
class QuerySet(...):
    ...
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        clone = self._clone()
        # Do some stuff and then
        return clone

    def _clone(self,...):
        klass = self.__class__
        obj = klass(...)
        return obj
```

So basically, every time a method is called, QuerySet will clone itself, instantiate a new object and return it.

My question is: WHY? Is my way wrong?
My fear is that the way I do it, something might break, otherwise I can't explain why Django team did what it did.

Comment: Returning a cloned object means that the original object is guaranteed immutability (you're changing the clone, not the original object).  That's just an observation on my part, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Seems very valid, looking at the explanation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#all

Comment: I'm looking at `git blame` output for that file, and I see `self._clone()` coming from several commits. Whatever the reason, this design was implemented consistently for a while now. https://github.com/django/django/blame/master/django/db/models/query.py

Comment: Thanks guys. Your pointers do imply that the reason was to give the user the option of reverting to the previous query

Comment: Can't your class extend `QuerySet`? that's the usual way to go.

Comment: @AdriánLópez, unfortunately no. Due to architecture requirements, we have to move our database behind a "wall" and communicate with it via a TCP/IP agent. So instead of querying, we will be sending requests. This is something out of Django's scope.

Comment: :/ seems like a lot of work, good luck :)

Comment: Actually, we only need a limited number of features: get, filter, exclude and all. So it is not much of a work. Need to override the Model's save() method and I'm almost done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does this so that the base query can be kept around and reused, without inheriting changes from a future "child" query, like your `exclude()` on your `filter()`. I'm guessing somebody tried storing queries for later, and realized that didn't work well without copying.

I cloned the django repo and did a quick `git log` on `django/db/models/query.py`, searching for the phrase `clone`.

The patch that introduces this change is here:

https://github.com/django/django/commit/d4a3a4b

Comment: Thanks @jpaugh! It looks like you nailed down the initial use of this method.